# Equivalent to java "Color.decode" in php or mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database with a string field called "color" from java
I keep the value so:

```
// (2=color field)
pst.setString (2, objeto.getBackground (). getRGB ())
```

and then I read it like this:

```
objeto.setBackground (Color.decode (rs.getString ("color")))
```

Is there any function in mysql or php to read the color?

Comment: What's the actual data that gets stored?

Comment: e.g. For rgb(2555, 0, 0) save -65536, for rgb(0,255,0) save -16711936...

Comment: Update your database to use unsigned values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you want exactly?

Convert a int to a color in #RRGGBB format?

```
sprintf('#%06X', $color);
```

or get the R, G, B values?

```
$r = ($color >> 16) & 0xFF;
$g = ($color >> 8) & 0xFF;
$b = ($color >> 0) & 0xFF;
```

or create a int from rgb values

```
$color = ($r & 0xFF) << 16 | ($g & 0xFF) << 8 | $b & 0xFF
```

Comment: Yes, I want to convert a int to color, but I've tried and do not match the colors, why when I save from java I recorded negative values​​?, thanks

Comment: Because you have signed values in Java

Comment: But if rgb(2555, 0, 0) save -65536, even if remove the sign do not match.

Comment: Java uses the Ones' complement to store negative int values(32bit), so -65536 is the same as 0xFF000000. To calculate the ones' complement you have to negate all bits of the value and add 1

Comment: Sorry, can you give me an example in php?

Comment: Please, how to negate all bits?  `$color=intval($row["color"])*-1;` not working.

Comment: You don't have to - as i said, php do this work internal for you.. `-65536` is the same as `0xFFFF0000`, which is a Color with alpha-channel 255(non transparent), and red=255. `$r = (-65536 >> 16) & 0xFF;`

Comment: Thanks! it works: `$color=intval($row["color"]);
$r = ($color >> 16) & 0xFF;
$g = ($color >> 8) & 0xFF;
$b = ($color >> 0) & 0xFF;
$color = ($r & 0xFF) << 16 | ($g & 0xFF) << 8 | $b & 0xFF;
$row["color"] = sprintf('#%06X', $color);`

Comment: You could also use `$color = ((int)$row["color"]) & 0xFFFFFF;` to get rid of the alpha channel